# jmeter-maven-plugin blocked at getting service port from "javax.xml.ws.Service" when executing JMX file

Tags: web-services, performance-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using jmeter-maven-plugin to run Performance test using JMX files:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gemalto.pse.pim</groupId>
            <artifactId>pim-ws-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFilesIncluded>
                            <jMeterTestFile>file_1.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                            <jMeterTestFile>file_2.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                        </testFilesIncluded>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The JMX file file_1.jmx execute a method in a class that call a web-service as follows:

```
final String ENDPOINT_ADDRESS = "http://10.256.45.147:8080/service-ejb/ServiceClass?wsdl";
final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(
        "http://service.tools.com/", "ServiceClassService");
javax.xml.ws.Service service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(
                new URL(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS), SERVICE_NAME);
IServiceClass myService = dataFinderService.getPort(IServiceClass.class);
```

The problem is that Jmeter plugin is blocked at execution of file_1.jmx and does not process the file_2.jmx, the process is blocked at:

```
IServiceClass myService = dataFinderService.getPort(IServiceClass.class);
```

And when i cancel the execution (type Ctrl+C) the process continues and Jmeter-maven-plugin generate the output report file

Any one have encounter this problem ? ... Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved, all what i implimented is right, the problem is just that i should use jmeter-maven-plugin version 1.8.0 instead of 1.9.0 :)

Comment: 1.8.0 wasn't running your JMeter tests in a separate JVM, whereas 1.9.0 does.  I suspect the real problem is that your class is not an explicit dependency added to the plugin so it can't be found when you use 1.9.0 and you are just getting lucky with 1.8.0 because it happens to be on the same class path.